# Why does this rand use statement work in rust?

Tags: random, rust, scope, traits

Following the example in the Rust book using its suggested `rand = "0.6.0"`, I get code that looks like this:

```
use rand::Rng;

fn main() {
    let secret_number = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1, 101);

    println!("The secret number is: {}", secret_number);
}
```

Everything the book says later on in its chapter on modules suggests that if you do a `use rand::Rng;` as above, you'll be able to use `Rng`. If that happens to be a module itself, you can use submodules with `Rng::submodule`. If that happens to be a type, you just use it as `Rng`. In the code above however, we never use `Rng` anywhere.

Instead, we use the seemingly unrelated `rand::thread_rng()`. From what I understand, since `rand` is the name of the top level crate, we should be able to use it, even without the `use` statement that doesn't appear to do anything.

Instead, for some reason, the program will fail to compile without the `use` statement. This is really confusing. I wish the book did a better job explaining what was happening there.

Why do we need the use statement? Why are we not using `Rng`? How is it related to `rand::thread_rng()`?

I come from a Python background, so I'm used to the idea that if you import `threading`, you're using `threading.something`. If you import `django.utils`, you're using `django.utils.something`. This seems like an import of `django.utils` where you're using the totally unrelated `django.urls`.

Comment: You actually ask two questions here. 1. Why is `Rng` imported with `use`? 2. Why can we use `thread_rng` though it hasn't been imported? The answer to the first question in the answer and comments below – you need to import traits in order to be able to use them. The answer to the second question is that you declare your dependencies in `Cargo.toml`, and since `rand` is in there, you can use fully qualified paths in that crate without any `use` statement; `use` in Rust isn't really "importing" anything – it just inserts a shortcut into the current namespace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot call trait methods unless the trait is in scope.

> In the code above however, we never use `Rng` anywhere.

You're using [`Rng`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.6.0/rand/trait.Rng.html). [`gen_range()`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.6.0/rand/trait.Rng.html#method.gen_range) is a trait method defined by the [`Rng`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.6.0/rand/trait.Rng.html) trait so [`Rng`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.6.0/rand/trait.Rng.html) must be in scope for you to call [`gen_range()`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.6.0/rand/trait.Rng.html#method.gen_range).

The nitty gritty details: [`rand::thread_rng()`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.6.0/rand/fn.thread_rng.html) returns [`ThreadRng`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.6.0/rand/rngs/struct.ThreadRng.html) which implements [`RngCore`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.6.0/rand/trait.RngCore.html) and gets an [`Rng`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.6.0/rand/trait.Rng.html) implementation because of the generic blanket impl [`impl<R> Rng for R where R: RngCore + ?Sized`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.6.0/rand/rngs/struct.ThreadRng.html#impl-Rng).

Comment: I'm sure your answer is technically accurate, but as someone just starting to learn Rust, despite having read the majority of the book at this point, I'm still lost. From what I gathered, the `rand::thread_rng()` function returns a `ThreadRng` struct, which accepts a generic type `R`, and tries to add methods to that by implementing the `Rng` trait on it. Something like that? It seems strange that as a user of the function, I should care about the internals of the function.

Comment: TL;DR: You're trying to use a trait method, and items from traits can only be used if the trait is in scope.

Comment: @mcarton Wow that makes sense. Thanks

Comment: @John I've updated my answer to be simpler and more straight-forward, if it answers your question please consider accepting it, thanks!